# $\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)=1+\sin(\theta)$ over the interval $(0,2\pi)$

Tags: trigonometry

$\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)=1+\sin(\theta)$ over the interval $0<\theta<2\pi$

Find the trigonometric identity.

Apologize for the confusion, first time using this resource didnt read the instructions. i have tried manipulating the equation by substituting x^2 and y^2 in for the cos^2 and sin^2 and subtracting and adding the one but i could not find out what identities to use to make both side equal. Sorry again for the mistake.

Comment: What have you tried? You might not know, but on this site you're expected to show some of your own effort. That probably explains why you've gotten a downvote

Comment: Find? No, you find. We help. What @ZachEffman said.

Comment: Oh right, also people really don't appreciate questions phrased as commands

Comment: Apologize for the confusion, first time using this resource didnt read the instructions. i have tried manipulating the equation by substituting x^2 and y^2 in for the cos^2 and sin^2 and subtracting and adding the one but i could not find out what identities to use to make both side equal. Sorry again for the mistake.

Comment: It is not an identity for all $\theta$ in $(0, 2\pi)$. You can check some values. Ex: Check $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2} $.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: $\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta = 1-2\sin^2\theta$, so your equation becomes: $$2\sin^2\theta + \sin \theta = 0.$$

Comment: I'm glad you answered this; I'm still trying to figure out where the question is!  ;-) ***Endorsed!!!*** Cheers!

Comment: I guided myself by the title!

Comment: It is not an identity, we can check $\theta$ in $(0, 2\pi)$ with $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Yes, that expression stated in the question is not an identity. Most probably OP couldn't express himself very well. The only exercise that makes sense there is solving the equation.